# How do I display a message when accessing a nonexistent file in NODE.JS?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an array of addresses. When I go to an address, there is a redirect to the site. The site reads the content from the file. I need to output a message when accessing a file that does not exist, but honestly i don't know how to do it in node.js

For example:

```
                res.send("<h1>ERROR! THIS SITE DOES NOT EXIST!</h1>")
```

My code:

```
const arr = ["/file", "/file2", "/file3", "/file4"]

            app.get(arr[0], function(req, res){
                console.log(req.url.substr(1)); 

                let filePath = req.url.substr(1);
                let s = fs.readFileSync(filePath + ".txt", "utf8");
                res.send("<h3>" + s + "</h3>");

            });
```

I will be grateful for any help.

P.S. I have tried to wrap my code in try-catch

```
    try {
   let s = fs.readFileSync(filePath + ".txt", "utf8");
   res.send("<h3>" + s + "</h3>");
}
catch(err) {
   res.send("<h3>ERROR</h3>");

}
```

But it doesn't work for some reason, all i got is standard **CANNOT GET/** message

Comment: And i have tried like: if (req.url != arr){'my code'}, but it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The question references "non-exist file" errors but it seems its actually your routing, and possibly the file error too.

Wrap the call in a `try-catch` statement and ensure your route definitions are correct like:

```
const arr = ["/file", "/file2", "/file3", "/file4"];

app.get(arr, function(req, res){
    console.log(req.url.substr(1));

    let filePath = req.url.substr(1);

    fs.readFile(filePath + ".txt", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({ message: `file not found etc.` });
        }

        res.send("<h3>" + data + "</h3>");
    });
});
```

If you want to catch any routes that are not matched and return something custom, then add a catch-all handler **at the end of all your route definitions** like this:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Route'+req.url+' Not found.' 
});
```

Comment: I tried to do as you said. But all what i got in the output is CANNOT GET/. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry, are you there?

Comment: The issue not reading the file it seems, it's your routing definition. Do you want to be able to match any route in that array: ["/file", "/file2", "/file3", "/file4"]?

Comment: YES! I want to do exactly what you described. If the requested address is not in the address array - display a message. I will be very appreciate if you show me how to do it in nodejs.

Comment: OK, it wasn't clear but I have updated the answer to address the routing

Comment: No server should EVER use `fs.readFileSync()` except in startup code.  That ruins the scalability of your  server.  I know that was in the OP's original code, but you need to also fix that because your recommendation is not complete without fixing that.

Comment: Thanks, It works! I just didn't know the syntax of it.

Comment: @jfriend00, I get that, but where do we draw the line? The majority of questions I try and answer have 80% surrounding code that I don't agree with and is not viable architecture. I don't turn every answer into consultation and rewrite their work. That would mean a rewrite of all this OP's existing code, dealing with many issues they have not raised in the question.

Comment: @SamuelG - My goal when I choose to write an answer is to write the best answer.  IMO, that includes pointing out other egregious things that are wrong in the code besides exactly what was asked about.  You don't have to rewrite to perfect code, but at least pointing out (or listing) the other major things that are wrong is part of a best answer (IMO).

Comment: @DenisAsh readFileSync is what is considered blocking io, meaning that the function will cause Node's event loop to wait while the file is read, which holds up the event loop. Take a read [here](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/) to understand more.

Comment: @DenisAsh - Use the asynchronous version: `fs.readFile()` or `fs.promises.readFile()` or if all you're doing is sending the file, then you can use [`res.sendFile()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile).  You can see that Samuel has included `fs.readFile()` in their answer now which is cool.